# Just a universally quantified hypotesis in coq proof

Tags: universal, coq, quantifiers

Another hard goal (for me, of course) is the following:

```
Goal ~(forall P Q: nat -> Prop,
  (exists x, P x) /\ (exists x, Q x) ->
  (exists x, P x /\ Q x)).
Proof.
```

I absolutely have no idea of what could I do. If I introduce something, I get a universal quantifier in the hypotesis, and then I can't do anything with it.

I suppose that it exists a standard way for managing such kind of situations, but I was not able to find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To progress in that proof, you will have to exhibit an instance of `P` and an instance of `Q` such that your hypothesis produces a contradiction.

A simple way to go is to use:

```
P : fun x => x = 0
Q : fun x => x = 1
```

In order to work with the hypothesis introduced, you might want to use the tactic `specialize`:

```
Goal ~(forall P Q : nat -> Prop,
  (exists x, P x) /\ (exists x, Q x) ->
  (exists x, P x /\ Q x)).
Proof.
  intro H.
  specialize (H (fun x => x = 0) (fun x => x = 1)).
```

It allows you to apply one of your hypothesis on some input (when the hypothesis is a function). From now on, you should be able to derive a contradiction easily.

Alternatively to `specialize`, you can also do:

```
  pose proof (H (fun x => x = 0) (fun x => x = 1)) as Happlied.
```

Which will conserve H and give you another term `Happlied` (you choose the name) for the application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ptival did the trick. Here is the code of the complete proof:

```
Goal ~(forall P Q: nat -> Prop,
  (exists x, P x) /\ (exists x, Q x) ->
  (exists x, P x /\ Q x)).
Proof.
  unfold not. intros.
  destruct (H (fun x => x = 0) (fun x => x = 1)).
    split.
      exists 0. reflexivity.
      exists 1. reflexivity.
    destruct H0. rewrite H0 in H1. inversion H1.
Qed.
```

Thank you!